# What is wrong with my attempt to compute $\int \frac{e^{x^2}(2x-1)}{e^x} dx$?

Tags: integration

I missed the use of the exponent rule here and tried to do it another way. I have no idea what's wrong with my attempt after looking at it so I must not understand something along the way. The correct answer should be $e^{(x-1)x}+C$ which I'm 99.9% sure is not equal to $e^x(2x-3)+C$ which is what I get. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

My attempt:

$$\int \dfrac{e^{x^2}(2x-1)}{e^x} dx.$$

Substitute:

$u = e^x$ $\implies ln(u) = x$, and $du = e^x dx$. This implies $\dfrac{du}{e^x} = dx \implies \dfrac{du}{u} = dx.$

Substituting in $u$ for $e^x$, and $\dfrac{du}{u}$ in for $dx$ we have, $$\int \dfrac{u^2(2ln(u)-1)}{u} \dfrac{du}{u}=\int \dfrac{u^2(2ln(u)-1)}{u^2}du=\int (2ln(u)-1)du.$$

Substitute:

$s = ln(u) \implies e^s = u$, and $ds = \dfrac{du}{u}$. This implies $u ds = du \implies e^sds = du$.

Substituting in $s$ for $ln(u)$, and $e^sds$ in for $du$ we have,

$$\int (2ln(u)-1)du=\int (2s-1)e^sds=\int (2se^s-e^s)ds=\int 2se^sds-\int e^sds.$$

By integration by parts $$\int 2se^sds= 2se^s-2e^s+C,$$

therefore, $$\int 2se^sds-\int e^sds=2se^s-2e^s-e^s+C=e^s(2s-3)+C.$$

Back substituting we have, $$e^s(2s-3)+C=e^{ln(u)}(2ln(u)-3)+C=u(2ln(u)-3)+C,$$

and, $$u(2ln(u)-3)+C=e^x(2x-3)+C.$$

Thus $$\int \dfrac{e^{x^2}(2x-1)}{e^x} dx=e^x(2x-3)+C.$$

Comment: $$u=e^x\implies u^2=e^{2x}\ne e^{x^2}$$

Comment: @Did A second too late!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error lies in the fact that if you apply the substitution $u=e^x$ to $e^{x^2}$, you *don't* get $u^2$. You would get $u^2$ if you were applying that substitution to $e^{2x}=(e^x)^2$.

Comment: The only answer so far that addresses the question in the title. +1.

Comment: @MPW I admit that that thought had already crossed my mind...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this as follows

> $$\int { \frac { e^{ x^{ 2 } }\left( 2x-1 \right)  }{ { e^{ x } } }  } dx=\int { { e }^{ { x }^{ 2 }-x } } d\left( { x }^{ 2 }-x \right) ={ e }^{ { x }^{ 2 }-x }+C$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that u²=e^2x and not e^x^2.....

but to substitute u=x²-x is far better then

$$\int \dfrac{e^{x^2}(2x-1)}{e^x} dx =\int e^u du$$